# Domain logon-dialog when opening "Computer management"

Tags: domain, group-policy

When I'm logged in to the domain on the client computer I need to logon to the domain again when I right-click "Computer" and chooses "Manage". No GPO has been set yet, and the user seems to be admin as well.

This problem is only when I logon domain. If I log in with local admin, everything is fine.

Why does it ask for the password again, and how can I prevent that?

Comment: Does the issue also occur if they run compmgmt.msc from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: Yes, because your domain user account is probably not a member of the local Administrators group. The local Administrator user account is, by default, a member of the local Administrators group. I would suggest you verify whether or not your domain user account is a member of the local Administrators group.

Comment: Yes, it seems the user wasn't local admin. Easy as that! Thanks! :)